# QML Calibri font pixelated when scaled

Tags: fonts, qml, qtquick2, qt-quick

When using Calibri font in QML `Text`/`TextEdit` item, with `scale` property applied, the rendered font looks really pixelated (as compared to other fonts e.g. Times New Roman; see image below).

This happens to me both on Windows 7 and Windows 10.

With `renderType` set to `Text.NativeRendering` even the Times New Roman looks ugly.

**Is this font issue? How can I workaround it?** I want to be able to show scaled Calibri smoothed.

[image: QML Calibri scaling issue]

The smallest repro I have is:

```qml
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0

Window {
    id: window

    width: 600
    height: 300

    title: "Calibri scaling issue"
    visible: true

    property string html: "<p style=\"font-family: Times New Roman\">Times New Roman<p>" +
                          "<p style=\"font-family: Calibri\">Calibri<p>"

    RowLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent

        Text {
            text: html
            textFormat: Text.RichText
        }
        Text {
            text: html
            textFormat: Text.RichText
            scale: 4
//            renderType: Text.NativeRendering
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right. It is strange, that `Times New Roman` has no such upscaling artifacts. Maybe you can work around it by rather down than upscaling, if scaling is necessary at all?

Comment: Seems like Text.QtRendering only supports some fonts (eg Arial and Time, but not Calibri, nor Courier). The result is the same if you try to rotate a Text: it will look fine with Time, but ugly with Calibri. I could not find a list of supported fonts. But as derM mentioned, scaling down might do the trick for you. You may also use font.pixelSize instead of scale.

Comment: @Yoann The thing is I already have rich text that I want to display as "zoomed". This makes the downscaling option not viable.

Comment: And what about using font.pixelSize? It won't work if your rich text contains font size data though...